# Set customer ID for Google Adwords API

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I try to use the Google Adwords API, with the official library here : https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib

I use an Manager Account on Google Adwords and want to work with my client's accounts.

I can get all the the Adwords account ID (like 123-456-7891) but I don't know how to pass the account ID to my Google Adwords functions as a parameter.

Here's my main function :

```
def main(argv):
    adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage(path="googleads.yaml")
    add_campaign(adwords_client)
```

I see any Account ID parameter in the official samples, as :

```
import datetime
import uuid
from googleads import adwords

def add_campaign(client):
  # Initialize appropriate services.
  campaign_service = client.GetService('CampaignService', version='v201809')
  budget_service = client.GetService('BudgetService', version='v201809')

  # Create a budget, which can be shared by multiple campaigns.
  budget = {
      'name': 'Interplanetary budget #%s' % uuid.uuid4(),
      'amount': {
          'microAmount': '50000000'
      },
      'deliveryMethod': 'STANDARD'
  }

  budget_operations = [{
      'operator': 'ADD',
      'operand': budget
  }]

  # Add the budget.
  budget_id = budget_service.mutate(budget_operations)['value'][0][
      'budgetId']

  # Construct operations and add campaigns.
  operations = [{
      'operator': 'ADD',
      'operand': {
          'name': 'Interplanetary Cruise #%s' % uuid.uuid4(),
          # Recommendation: Set the campaign to PAUSED when creating it to
          # stop the ads from immediately serving. Set to ENABLED once you've
          # added targeting and the ads are ready to serve.
          'status': 'PAUSED',
          'advertisingChannelType': 'SEARCH',
          'biddingStrategyConfiguration': {
              'biddingStrategyType': 'MANUAL_CPC',
          },
          'endDate': (datetime.datetime.now() +
                      datetime.timedelta(365)).strftime('%Y%m%d'),
          # Note that only the budgetId is required
          'budget': {
              'budgetId': budget_id
          },
          'networkSetting': {
              'targetGoogleSearch': 'true',
              'targetSearchNetwork': 'true',
              'targetContentNetwork': 'false',
              'targetPartnerSearchNetwork': 'false'
          },
          # Optional fields
          'startDate': (datetime.datetime.now() +
                        datetime.timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y%m%d'),
          'frequencyCap': {
              'impressions': '5',
              'timeUnit': 'DAY',
              'level': 'ADGROUP'
          },
          'settings': [
              {
                  'xsi_type': 'GeoTargetTypeSetting',
                  'positiveGeoTargetType': 'DONT_CARE',
                  'negativeGeoTargetType': 'DONT_CARE'
              }
          ]
      }
  }, {
      'operator': 'ADD',
      'operand': {
          'name': 'Interplanetary Cruise banner #%s' % uuid.uuid4(),
          'status': 'PAUSED',
          'biddingStrategyConfiguration': {
              'biddingStrategyType': 'MANUAL_CPC'
          },
          'endDate': (datetime.datetime.now() +
                      datetime.timedelta(365)).strftime('%Y%m%d'),
          # Note that only the budgetId is required
          'budget': {
              'budgetId': budget_id
          },
          'advertisingChannelType': 'DISPLAY'
      }
  }]
  campaigns = campaign_service.mutate(operations)
```

How can I tell Adwords API in which account I want to add this campaign ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4):

OK my bad, I missed a documentation method (http://googleads.github.io/googleads-python-lib/googleads.adwords.AdWordsClient-class.html#SetClientCustomerId).

```
    # ID of your customer here
    CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID = '4852XXXXX'

    # Load customer account access
    client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage(path="googleads.yaml")
    client.SetClientCustomerId(CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID)
```

And the customer ID is now associate with the AdwordsClient variable as "client" set as parameters for other functions.